# Why doesn't this method invocation invoke the derived class?

Tags: c#, generics, interface

I have an interface `IDeepCloneable`, that I'm using to implement generic deep copying. I have a base class and a derived class as well, each implementing `IDeepCloneable`. I'm running into issues with derived classes.

Here is the code:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var a = new BaseClass();
        var ac = a.DeepClone();

        var b = (BaseClass)(new DerivedClass());
        var bc = b.DeepClone();
    }
}

public interface IDeepCloneable<T>
{
    T DeepClone();
}

public class BaseClass : IDeepCloneable<BaseClass>
{
    public string Value { get; set; }

    public BaseClass(){}
    public BaseClass(BaseClass copy)
    {
        Value = copy.Value;
    }

    public BaseClass DeepClone()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("BLAH1");
        return new BaseClass(this);
    }
}

public class DerivedClass : BaseClass, IDeepCloneable<DerivedClass>
{
    public string SomeOtherValue { get; set; }

    public DerivedClass(){}
    public DerivedClass(DerivedClass copy)
        : base(copy)
    {
        SomeOtherValue = copy.SomeOtherValue;
    }

    public new DerivedClass DeepClone()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("BLAH2");
        return new DerivedClass(this);
    }
}
```

This outputs:

```
BLAH1
BLAH1
```

I understand why it outputs BLAH1 twice, I'm just not sure how to fix it..

Comment: Did you know that creating deepcopy's with the BinaryFormatter is way easier and faster?

Comment: @Sievajet I looked into it and didn't want to litter my api with serializable, however now I'm reconsidering :)

Comment: The JsonConvert doesnt require iserializable attributes, try using that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your derived class needs to `override` the `DeepClone()` method, and your `DeepClone` method in the base class needs to be `virtual`.

Right now, your `DeepClone` method in the derived class is unrelated (other than having the same name) to the base class. See [Interface Implementation Inheritance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664593(v=vs.71).aspx) in the C# standard.

That said, it looks like you're trying to do deep copies. Have you considered using a [`BinaryFormatter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter(v=vs.110).aspx) to serialize and de-serialize your data?

Comment: If I override in the derived class, then the return value has to be a BaseClass

Comment: @ConditionRacer But a `DerivedClass` _is a_ `BaseClass`, so what's the issue?

Comment: @ConditionRacer So which is more important to you, returning the compile time type of the object, or returning the actual runtime type of the object?  You can have one, not both.

Comment: @DStanley It will cease to fulfill the interface's contract.  Interface implementations are not allowed to use type variance on the parameters or return values.

Comment: @Servy I was presuming the OP would change the return type to `BaseClass`

Comment: @Servy I want DeepClone to always return the runtime type

Comment: @ConditionRacer Then that's your choice.  You'll need to deal with the fact that the compile time type of the return value won't match.  Or you could just avoid creating clonable objects that have any inheritance, and make your life so much easier.

Comment: @Servy How? Composition?

Answer (score 1):

since that base class or yours implements the interface already, so you can either make the base class's DeepClone method as virtual and override it, or you can do

```
public abstract class BaseClass : IDeepCloneable<T>
...
public abstract T DeepClone(){}
```

and in your DerivedClass do

```
public class DerivedClass : BaseClass<DerivedClass>
```